# null-safe Collection contains method

Tags: java, collections, apache-commons-collection

What's the best way to do null-safe `contains` on a Java collection?

in other words -

```
 if (collection != null && collection.contains(x))
```

?

I was hoping Apache commons-collections had something like `CollectionUtils.contains(collection, x)` that would simply return false if the collection was null, as there is with `size()`, which treats null like an empty collection.

However, it seems like there is no such thing - did I just miss it?

Comment: What is the problem with `collection != null && collection.contains(x)`? Simple and no external dependencies!

Comment: @AbhinavSarkar:This is what I was thinking!

Comment: Here's a somewhat related post, by someone who didn't want to deal with checking for null all the time: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/271526/avoiding-null-statements-in-java

Comment: Note that if `x` is null, there are bigger problems.  Even if you've checked that `collection` is not null, there are some kinds of collection (such as a `TreeSet` without its own `Comparator`) for which `collection.contains(null)` will throw a `NullPointerException`, where you'd really want it to simply return `false`.  I am still looking for a null-safe way to do `collection.contains(x)`, without explicitly catching this exception.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You should instead be applying the **Null Object Pattern** here and use an empty collection, rather than a null collection. Of course, perhaps this is appropriate for your problem, but without more context it's hard to tell. In other words, I think you are solving the wrong problem -- why might `collection` be null in the first place?

Comment: In general I agree.  Specific issue is that the collection is coming from `session.getAttribute` and thus may never have been set.  So at least one not-null check is unavoidable - but if there were multiple such checks, yes, I could simply have a single check and replace with an empty collection.

Comment: In that case, consider using Guava's optional, perhaps? The problem is that still leaves you with a check for Optional.isPresent(). I think it's basically unavoidable.

Answer (score 1):

Do it like this:

```
CollectionUtils.emptyIfNull(collection).contains(x)
```

There is also an equivalent version for `SetUtils`, `MapUtils`, `ListUtils`, etc.

This code is longer, so it seems to me it's mainly useful when you need a single expression for a Lambda.